# Resources to self-study counting/sorting networks

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, parallel-computing, concurrency

I am reading The Art of Multiprocessor Programming. I was able to grasp almost everything up to Counting Networks in chapter 12 - Counting Sorting and Distributed Coordination. However I am having trouble understanding counting and sorting networks.

Does someone know a bit beginner friendly resource about counting/sorting networks?

Thanks.

Comment: Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms used to have an introduction to sorting networks. It has been removed in more recent editions but if you find an older copy in the library it might be a good start. It is a basic well presented introduction to sorting networks. Perhaps not exactly what you need, but a start.

Comment: Thanks @Michel. I'll check if I can find the 1st edition.

Comment: If you have no luck, send me a message through this forum and I will help further.  Not sure how to do messaging on here, but I assume it can be done.